# How to add Custom UX into Sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Might be basic question, but can some one please clarify how can i include custom ux into my Sencha touch application.

Here are the details
1. I'm adding youtubeplayer into sencha touch (http://code.google.com/p/ext-ux-youtubeplayer/downloads/detail?name=ext-ux-youtubeplayer-0.5.rar&can=2&q=)

1. I've downloaded and placed in root folder of my app 
   (C:\xampp\htdocs\Sencha_New\touch-2.2.0\kids\ux)
2. i added this entry in app.js

   //
   Ext.Loader.setPath({
       'Ext': 'touch/src',
       'kids': 'app',
       'Ext.ux.YoutubePlayer': './ux/ext-ux-youtubeplayer' //Pavan - added for Youtube player EXTJS
   });
3. added this entry in app\sencha.cfg

   app.classpath=${app.dir}/app.js,${app.dir}/app,ux

When i try to instantiate this, getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'YoutubePlayer' of undefined

Thanks
Pavan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... in my app.js I have a Ux plugin I use, but my call to `setPath` looks like this:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
  'Ext': 'touch/src',
  'MyApp': 'app',
  'Ux': 'vendor/Ux'
});
```

The class of the plugin is `Ux.layout.Accordion` and my folder structure is like this:

```
root
|_app
|_resources
...
|_vendor
 |_Ux
  |_layout
   |_Accordion.js
```

The corresponding line in my sencha.cfg is:

```
app.classpath=${app.dir}/vendor,${app.dir}/app.js,${app.dir}/app
```

I'm wondering if your `setPath` arguments are correct, perhaps you should not fully expand the class name? Also the paths should be relative to your `index.html` file I'm pretty sure.

Comment: perfect.. that's the answer :)